# pdf and word viewers in android

Tags: android, android-library, pdf-viewer

I need to show the pdf and the word files from the sdcard into the application.
I am looking out for libraries that can be integrated for this.

There are a few which I surfed:
1) Vudroid
2) jBlough
3) apdf and so on...
4) olive (for word)

I need a library which can show both these formats or either of the two.
Secondly, which one would be a better to go with. I was unable to find the libraries apart from the jBlough and olive. Can somebody aid me with few links for these libraries?

Note: I am not looking for implicit intent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Document Viewer and Converter for Android](https://github.com/AsposeShowcase/Document_Viewer_and_Converter_for_Android). It is MIT licensed Android application that can view Microsoft Word, RTF and OpenDocument Text files and convert them to PDF, DOCX, DOC, ODT, RTF and HTML.

The application uses [Aspose.Words for Android](http://www.aspose.com/android/word-component.aspx) to process, render and convert the documents and uses some basic Android platform's features to lazy-load and cache page previews.

Disclosure: I am a developer at Aspose.

Comment: Is there any solution to read ppt files and display it in android.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library:

http://www.csr.com/products/directoffice-mobile-sdk

It will convert Office and PDF to PNG or PDF.  The PNG files are easy to display in your app.